# Iron Python - No module named "os"

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

I have been trying to debug this sample code, but I am having trouble.

**Here is the code:**

```
import System
import get_events_devices
from System.Windows.Forms import *
from System.ComponentModel import *
from System.Drawing import *
from clr import *
clr.AddReference("IronPython") 

class Check: # namespace

    class Form1(System.Windows.Forms.Form):
        """type(_label1) == System.Windows.Forms.Label, type(_button1) == System.Windows.Forms.Button"""
        __slots__ = ['_label1', '_button1']
        def __init__(self):

            self.InitializeComponent()

        @accepts(Self(), bool)
        @returns(None)
        def Dispose(self, disposing):

            super(type(self), self).Dispose(disposing)

        @returns(None)
        def InitializeComponent(self):
            self._button1 = System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            self._label1 = System.Windows.Forms.Label()
            self.SuspendLayout()
            # 
            # button1
            # 
            self._button1.Location = System.Drawing.Point(58, 61)
            self._button1.Name = 'button1'
            self._button1.Size = System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            self._button1.TabIndex = 0
            self._button1.Text = 'Click'
            self._button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
            self._button1.Click += self._button1_Click
            # 
            # label1
            # 
            self._label1.AutoSize = True
            self._label1.Location = System.Drawing.Point(190, 70)
            self._label1.Name = 'label1'
            self._label1.Size = System.Drawing.Size(0, 13)
            self._label1.TabIndex = 1
            # 
            # Form1
            # 
            self.ClientSize = System.Drawing.Size(292, 273)
            self.Controls.Add(self._label1)
            self.Controls.Add(self._button1)
            self.Name = 'Form1'
            self.Text = 'Form1'
            self.ResumeLayout(False)
            self.PerformLayout()

        @accepts(Self(), System.Object, System.EventArgs)
        @returns(None)
        def _button1_Click(self, sender, e):

            # Snippet Statement
            pass
            # End Snippet Statement
            self._label1.Text = 'mohsin'
            get_events_devices.units()
```

I have just added optparse.py, get_events_devices.py, and iron python.dll.

From where I get ironpython_module.dll as I have install Iron Python I am not getting this .dll?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?  Your comments in your 'question' don't seem to have anything to do with the subject, either.

Comment: i have told that what dlls i have added and the code is right over there but after that i am getting error as subject in get_events_devices.py ?? got it

Comment: Give us the actual error traceback.

Comment: it should be obvious that we don't understand what you're asking. Telling me what you have in your 'question' does not help at all.

Comment: Please write a short paragraph explaining this sentence in your question "From where I get ironpython_module.dll as I have install Iron Python I am not getting this .dll?" and post the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are running and debugging the Python code using Visual Studio via the IronPython tools, it might be that your `sys.path` does not contain a reference to all of the IronPython modules such as `os`.

In your code, try adding the following to indicate the install directory of IronPython:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
```

The above is a workaround for [this reported bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30348).

Answer (score 2):

In the python scripts, you need explicitly import lib path of os.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("c:\python27\lib")
```

This code worked for me and resolved the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer is a duplicate of the highest voted response. Worse, it provides even less information. Please read over the responses that have already been provided before responding yourself.